# ZSH treat value as literal string

Tags: arrays, linux, string, config, zsh

As part of the ZSH theme I am setting up, I need to get a list of programs from the various executable directories (i.e. `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, etc), and then pass that to an array.

At the moment, I just dump a bunch of `ls` commands into one file and then from there I read each line of that file into an array.

The problem is, is that the very first line in the file is `[`, which when my ZSH config tries to set that to the array via `set -A $progarr $progline` (where `$progarr` is the array and `$progctr` is an iterator inside the loop that handles the file reading) I receive the error `/home/user/.zshrc:57: not an identifier: [`

Is there a way I can tell the script "just treat whatever `$progline` is as a string and therefore don't try to interpret it in any way"?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you used `$progarr` instead of just `progarr` -- that means that the value of the first element of `progarr` is used, except it's empty at that point, so there's no array name being supplied. Essentially, the command expands from:

```
set -A $progarr $progline
```

to

```
set -A [
```

and `[` isn't a valid name for an array, so you get an error.

Other problems: it looks like you're setting the array to just `$progline` (replacing its previous contents) instead of appending it. And [parsing `ls`'s output is generally problematic](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

I'd recommend using wildcards to get the list directly:

```
set -A progarr /bin/* /sbin/* /usr/bin/* /usr/sbin/*    # Create array of commands
progarr=("${progarr[@]##*/}")    # Trim off the paths (e.g. "/bin/ls" -> "ls")
```

Comment: Awesome, that did what I needed to do! Thanks for that link about parsing ls output, I'll have to keep that in mind.

Could you go into more detail on that second line? It's my understanding that ${progarr[@]} represents all indexes in the array, but what exactly is that "##*/" bit doing? I'm guessing it means "get rid of everything from the beginning to the last "/", but could you explain in more detail?

Comment: @BenjaminDennison That's essentially it. The `${name##pattern}` removes the longest match of `pattern` from the beginning of the value (see [here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion)); the pattern `*/` matches from the beginning through a "/", so the longest match removes through the last "/". And zsh allows you to combine this with `[@]` to apply it to each element of the array individually.